# Estimating a negative binomial regression in R

Tags: r, regression, poisson, invariants

I am having trouble finding out how to properly estimate the following negative binomial regression. The regression is:

[Negative Binomial Regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7qgK.png)

- Di,t is the number of COVID-19 deaths in country i on day t.
- Xm,i,t is variable m for country i on day t. I have the number of people testing positive for COVID-19 in country i on day t. I lag this variable by 14 days from the literature. I also have a trend and trend squared, which start on the first day a person tests positive in country i on day t.
- Zn,i are country specific variables, which do not vary over time, or time invariant variables. These variables are economic freedom, real GDP growth rate, medical doctors per 1,000, percent of population age 65 and older, etc.
- The original model had deaths in country i on day t divided by the country's population (Pi). I moved the population to the right side as an offset.

My paper was already rejected by one journal because I estimated the whole equation as a negative binomial. He said by repeating the time invariant variables introduced correlation into the regression.

I have two questions.

- How do I estimate this equation, easily? The focus of the paper is on the time invariant factors. My hypothesis is economically free countries exhibit a lower COVID-19 death rate because they are more resilient. I also write all the code in R.
- Are there papers I can cite that use this type of regression?

Any help is appreciated.